# How to force symfony2 to use HTTPS only for one page

Tags: php, symfony, https, symfony-2.1, symfony-routing

I have to use HTTPS for only single page in symfony2 app. I've tried like

**security.yml**

```
- { path: ^/payment, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
```

It works good but when i navigate to other pages from /payment page its stays same in HTTPS instead of HTTP. I've also tried something from sonata admin controller like:

**PaymentAdmin.php**

```
$collection
        ->add('makePayment', 'payment/{paymentId}',$options = array('_scheme' => 'https'));
```

but the same problem.simply i just want to use HTTPS only for /payment page not for other pages.how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding regexp start notation "^" to your path like this "^/payment" which should state that routes which start with /payment should be in "https".

```
{ path: ^/payment, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
```

The example in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html
also shows that.

Comment: You also could try adding "$" to end of path like this ^/payment$ which then should work only form route /payment and not it's sub routes.

Comment: yes, i did the same but my problem is my whole site is using **http** if once i visit /payment page it changed to **https** and never revert back to **http**. i just want **https** for /payment page.

Comment: Have you tried adding { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: http } this should enforce http on all routes and if you leave https settings for /payment, it should switch when moving between /payment and the rest of the site.

Comment: You could also try enforcing https for controller when defining route by adding schemes:  [https] option.

Comment: yes,i have tried like, adding { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: http } in security.yml and then add routing option as  schemes: https in controller but controller option doesn't override security.yml option.

Comment: if you defined you options in this order :                            { path: ^/payment, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }        { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: http } , you may try switch them like this                                                       { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: http }                { path: ^/payment, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }, thought not sure if that will help, but ordering sometimes is really important. at least in routing.

Comment: Thanks @sepikas it's works fine with minor change in path pattern. i've used used **/payment** instead of **^/payment**